# Ash uses phrase "Kane's son" in discussing the creature -- was this in the original version?

Tags: dialogue, alternate-version, alien

I'm rewatching *Alien* on HBOMax and I heard Ash call the creature "Kane's son". I think HBOMax often has versions different than theatrical release or maybe because I am watching on a laptop I can hear better and rewind. But I saw the original version in 1979 and I think the director's cut and also probably rented the tape -- I just don't recall this memorable line which was spoken I guess a little quietly.

Is this line only in certain versions of Alien?

To be clear, Kane is the name of the character who was attacked by the face-hugger and then "gave birth" to the chest-burster -- not sure if Kane was chosen for the biblical reference or not.

https://clip.cafe/alien-1979/well-air-shaft-may-work-our-advantage/

Comment: I definitely know the line, too, so it's not just some HBO cut. But I can't say if it's only in the Director's Cut.

Comment: Strange thing for an android to say. Ash was no regular android, very human affect; this is shown in multiple places in the film. Ian Holm acted just like a human. He waves from the bridge and smiles. He shows impatience when Ripley asks him to explain how the tracking device works.

Comment: Well, he was also supposed to fool *us*, not just the crew. It's certainly an important thing to say, considering the common rape interpretation of the film.

Comment: the only way you can make an android so human is by using human engrams and even then the android knowing he is not human is a huge hurdle in acting naturally.

Comment: I...don't really think the technical intricacies of *how* an android can be so human is something the film was particularly concerned about.

Comment: "Kane's son" - https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/cLkAAOSwH~NkH9dt/s-l500.jpg